# How to get raw notification in background

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, window-handles

How does messenger like whats app is saving data when WhatsApp is not running? Suppose a scenario: a message is received by the user but at that time he/she didn't act upon. A few minutes Later he/she got disconnected from the internet then opens the messenger.

He/She find his/her message saved in their whats app even the user didn't respond to that notification neither the app contacted the server as when opening the app there is no internet connection.

Then how the above scenario became possible??